# Display the value of a field list in views

Tags: views

suppose we have this field list:

```
Status
  1 => foo
  2 => bar
  3 => foo_bar
```

in the views page I want to display

```
Status
------
foo
bar
foo_bar
```

but now it give me:

```
Status
------
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, click on the field, under Formatter select 'Default'.